# refer 1st child object from 2nd child object through parent

Tags: custom-object, formula, dependent-picklist

I have a requirement in which i have 2 child objects:Agreement__C & Payments_Due__c and parent object: Policy_Holder__c.Now i want to create formula field on picklist so that i can refer Agreement__c obj field from Payments_Due__c obj.I have checked cross object formula field but by that we can go from child to multiple parents.

Any ideas!!Also how can i create formula on picklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to a child object from a parent's formula. What you may be able to do, depending on your needs, is to create one or more [rollup summary fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=0) on the Policy_Holder__c object to summarize the Payment_Due__c data you're interested in, and from there, you can refer to it from the Agreement__c object. To use a picklist in your formulas, you generally need to use the ISPICKVAL, CASE, or TEXT formula operators, which allow you to compare to a specific value, a list of values, or convert the value to text, respectively. You can read more about those functions in the [Formula Operator and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=0) documentation.